# stub an instance variable inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm using rspec 1.3.2 to test a controller action that looks something like this:

```
def action_foo
  ...
  @bar.can_do_something?
  ...
end
```

I'm trying to stub `@bar` (assume it's an instance of class `Bar`) instance variable but am unable to. I think if I had access to `any_instance` then I could do `Bar.any_instance.stub(:can_do_something?)` but that's not available in the version of rspec I am using.

Is there another way to access and stub `@bar`? None of the following worked:

```
@bar.stub(:can_do_something?)
controller.instance_variable_get("@bar").stub(:can_do_something?)
controller.stub_chain(:bar, :can_do_something?)
Bar.new.stub(:can_do_something?)
```

Edit:

`@bar` is assigned in a `before_filter`. something like `@bar = Bar.find(n)`

Comment: Where/how is `@bar` instantiated?

Comment: `@bar` is assigned in a `before_filter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, this is a bit cleaner I think:

```
bar = Bar.new # or use FactoryGirl to create a Bar factory
bar.stub(:can_do_something?) { # return something }
controller.instance_variable_set(:@bar, bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Bar.any_instance.stub(:can_do_something?)
```

Comment: `@bar` is assigned in a `before_filter`

Comment: So do: `Bar.should_receive(:find).and_return your_object_or_mock`

Comment: It's `allow_any_instance_of(Bar).to receive(:can_do_something?).and_return true` nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails you could do something similar to any_instance.stub. For the record, this makes me feel dirty.

```
Bar.class_eval do
  alias :original_can_do_something? :can_do_something?

  def can_do_something?  # "stub" method
    # Return whatever you need here
  end
end

# Run your test

Bar.class_eval do
  alias :can_do_something? :original_can_do_something?  # "unstub" the method
end
```

Comment: i'm not going with this solution but accepting your answer since it's the only one that answered my question